# c# Compare 2 CSV files and delete if it exists in second file

Tags: c#, csv

Basically i want to delete a row from List.csv if it exists in the ListToDelete.csv and output the results to a different file named newList.csv.

List.csv
1,A,V
2,B,W
3,C,X
4,D,Y
5,E,z

ListToDelete.csv
3
4

NewList.csv
1,A,V
2,B,W
5,E,z

I understand about using streamreader and writer to read and write to files but i can't see how to store only the first column of List.csv to compare it to the 1st column of ListToDelete.csv.

I initially stripped out everything in the first column using the split method to do the comparison but i also need to copy over the other 2 columns and i can't see how to compare or loop through it correctly.

```
string list = "List.txt";
        string listDelete = "ListToDelete.txt";
        string newList = "newList.txt";

        //2 methods to store all the text in a string array so we can match the arrays. Using ReadAllLines instead of screenreader so it populates array automatically
        var array1 = File.ReadAllLines(list);
        var array2 = File.ReadAllLines(listDelete);

        // Sets all the first columns from the CSV into an array
        var firstcolumn = array1.Select(x => x.Split(',')[0]).ToArray();
        //Matches whats in firstcolumn and array 2 to find duplicates and non duplicates
        var duplicates = Array.FindAll(firstcolumn, line => Array.Exists(array2, line2 => line2 == line));
        var noduplicates = Array.FindAll(firstcolumn, line => !Array.Exists(duplicates, line2 => line2 == line));

        //Writes all the non duplicates to a different file
        File.WriteAllLines(newList, noduplicates);
```

So that above code produces
1
2
5

But i also need the second and third columns to be written to a new file to look like

NewList.csv
1,A,V
2,B,W
5,E,z

Comment: does the code in my answer work for you? just replace this line.

Comment: Hi Kenny, the code you provided works but it still doesn't produce the second and third column in the new output file

Comment: The problem is because `noduplicates` is selected from `firstcolumn`, which is `{1,2,3,4,5}`. I believe I had fixed this: I select from the original list (`array1`), excluding the two lines starts with `3`/`4`.

Comment: Ofcourse, i apologise, i missed that. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had almost done it right. The problem is because `noduplicates` is selected from `firstcolumn`, which is only the first column `{1,2,3,4,5}`. `noduplicates` should be selected from the original list (array1), excluding the lines that start with one of the duplicates.

Correct one single line as following should fix the problem. The output has 3 rows and each row has 3 columns.

```
var noduplicates = Array.FindAll(array1, line => !Array.Exists(duplicates, line2 => line.StartsWith(line2)));
```

Furthermore, you don't need to parse the first column from the original array for matching. The code can be cleaned up like this

```
string list = "List.csv";
string listDelete = "ListToDelete.csv";
string newList = "newList.txt";

var array1 = File.ReadAllLines(list);
var array2 = File.ReadAllLines(listDelete);

var noduplicates = Array.FindAll(array1, line => !Array.Exists(array2, line2 => line.StartsWith(line2)));

//Writes all the non duplicates to a different file
File.WriteAllLines(newList, noduplicates);
```